# Php code not executing on web browsers

Tags: php, xampp, mariadb, dreamweaver

I am new to php. I have installed Dreamweaver CC and XAMPP server. I have set up my site definition on Dreamweaver and everything seems fine. The server is connected and is running. But when I run my php code on my browser, it's not executing.

Rather, I get the following error:

> Y??? 5.5.5-10.1.10-MariaDB?=???V}4(j'!"? Y÷?? ?????????????????&8#08SO1Got packets out of order.

What does this mean? How can I get my code to work properly?

Secondly, when I run a simple "Hello world" php file on the server which I created, it shows a blank page.

Can anyone please help me? I have been stuck here for a week now without any progress. I am using Window 7 Ultimate currently.

Comment: You seem to be attempting to connect your browser to MySQL. Something's misconfigured or you're hitting the wrong port. Not really anything to do with PHP at all. If you're visiting a URL along the lines of `http://localhost:3306/` take the `:3306` out.

Comment: still the same issue.  I did just as you said, didnt work.

yea, that was what i was trying to do, connect browser to MYSQL.

Comment: Again, you cannot connect your browser directly to MySQL like this. You've gotta connect to a webserver, which will run some PHP, and the *PHP* is what connects to MySQL.

Comment: Please just provide more suggestions, cos i have gone through alot of forum to get answers, still not working

Comment: If you are getting this error at `http://localhost/` without a port, you've gone and messed up the XAMPP configuration - undo those changes. If you get a blank page there, you've got some sort of PHP error - the details will be in the logs, and we'd need a) the error and b) the PHP code that causes it to debug further.

Comment: Ok, After installation of xampp, i didnt do any configuration or made an alteration. What i did was to hit the start button to run the server and is running very fine.

Even Dreamweaver is connected to the server and is running fine

Comment: Then read the rest of my comment and act accordingly. If you get the "Got packets out of order." at `http://localhost/` *something* is badly misconfigured to set MySQL's port to 80.